# Cambiar el grafico de barras de vertical a horizontal

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

me gustaría saber como cambiar la orientación del gráfico. la salida por defecto es vertical y no logro hacer que cambie a horizontal. muchas gracias desde ya

````
import numpy as np

medidas=('verde', 'amarillo','rojo')
y = ['0-7,5 cm','7,5-15 cm','15-22,5 cm','22,5-30 cm','30-30,5 cm']

verde_1 = np.array([10,11,12,13,14])
amarillo_1 = np.array([20,21,22,23,24])
rojo_1 = np.array([30,31,32,33,34])

plt.bar(y, verde_1,width=0.5,color='green')
plt.bar(y, amarillo_1,bottom = verde_1,width=0.5,color='yellow')
plt.bar(y, rojo_1,bottom=verde_1 + amarillo_1,width=0.5,color = 'red')

plt.title('penetrometro')
plt.xlabel('profundidad')
plt.ylabel('porcentaje')
plt.legend(labels=medidas)

plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar [`matplotlib.pyplot.barh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html), pero debes cambiar dos cosas dado que cambias la orientación de las barras:

- El argumento `bottom` por `left`.
- El argumento `width` por `height`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


medidas=('verde', 'amarillo','rojo')
y = ['0-7,5 cm','7,5-15 cm','15-22,5 cm','22,5-30 cm','30-30,5 cm']

verde_1 = np.array([10,11,12,13,14])
amarillo_1 = np.array([20,21,22,23,24])
rojo_1 = np.array([30,31,32,33,34])

plt.barh(y, verde_1, height=0.5, color='green')
plt.barh(y, amarillo_1, left=verde_1, height=0.5, color='yellow')
plt.barh(y, rojo_1, left=verde_1 + amarillo_1, height=0.5, color='red')

plt.title('penetrometro')
plt.xlabel('profundidad')
plt.ylabel('porcentaje')
plt.legend(labels=medidas)

plt.show()
```

Se podría usar `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` y su argumento `orientation`, pero la documentación lo desaconseja:

> ```
> orientation{'vertical', 'horizontal'}, optional
>
>     This is for internal use only.
>     Please use barh for horizontal bar plots. Default: 'vertical'.
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sos un genio muchísimas gracias!